# Angular set style from ngStyle directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working with Angular 7 here. I want to render image which is inside an `*ngFor` loop. All these images have different height so I want to set the height of image from the returned data. Here is code for reference

```html
<div *ngFor="let image of images" class="image-container">
  <img mat-card-image src="{{image.webformatURL}}">
  <p>image height:{{ image.previewHeight }}</p>
</div>
```

In the example above, I'm getting my height in pixels with `{{ image.previewHeight }}` which I wanted for `<img>` tag. Looking for a solution that is similar to this

```html
<img mat-card-image  style="height:{{ image.previewHeight }}" src="{{image.webformatURL}}">
```

I've tried this but its giving error on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use NgStyle directive:

```
<img mat-card-image  [ngStyle]="{'height.px': image.previewHeight}" src="{{image.webformatURL}}">
```

Reference: [NgStyle_API](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a specific style by using the style binding syntax.

https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/

```html
<img mat-card-image 
     [style.height.px]="image.previewHeight" 
     src="{{image.webformatURL}}">
```